# Iterating through javascript HashTable without causing optimization loss

Tags: javascript, v8

According to the 5.2.1 section of this article: [Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)

Doing this turns optimizations off in V8:

```
function hashTableIteration() {
    var hashTable = {"-": 3};
    for(var key in hashTable);
}
```

and the author says:

An object will go into hash table mode for example when you add too many properties    dynamically (outside constructor), delete properties, use properties that cannot be     valid identifiers and so on. In other words, when you use an object as if it was a hash 
table, it will be turned into a hash table. Passing such an object to for-in is a no no. You can tell if an object is in hash table mode by calling `console.log(%HasFastProperties(obj))` when the flag --allow-natives-syntax is enabled in Node.JS.

My question is then what is the correct way of iterating through the keys of a hashtable-like object in javascript, so that optimization do not get turned off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the answer lies at the bottom of the very same article.

> Workaround: Always use  Object.keys  and iterate over the array with
>   for loop. If you truly need all properties from entire prototype
>   chain, make an isolated helper function:

```
function inheritedKeys(obj) {
  var ret = [];
  for(var key in obj) {
    ret.push(key);
  }
  return ret; 
}
```

> If you pass a object to  for-in  that is not a simple enumerable it
>   will punish the entire containing function.

From what I understood, the isolated function would help in allowing the rest of the process to be optimized. Only the `inheritedkeys` function wouldn't be optimized in the example below.

```
function someFunction(someObj) {
    var keys = inheritedKeys(someObj),
        i = 0,
        len = keys.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        //some computation
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe `Object.keys` is regularly a better alternative in performance.  However, I cannot say whether the optimizer converts it to a hashtable if used.

Update: Adding code for others stumbling upon this question.

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObj);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var value = myObj[keys[i]];
}
```